# YARD how to document a @param of Array<Array<String>>

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

Let's say I have the following function:

```rb
@param foo [Array<String>]
def recursive_split(foo)
  bar = []
  foo.each do |elem|
    bar.append(elem.split(''))
  end
  bar
end
```

How do I document with the yard `@return` tag that my return value is an array of arrays of strings ? Is `@return [Array<Array<String>>]` the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs aren't that specific](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#declaring-types) but types specifiers are recursive so the `X` in `Array<X>` can be any list of valid types so these:

```
Array<String>
Array<String, Symbol>
Array<Array<String, Symbol, #m>>
Array<String, Array<#m>>
...
```

are all valid.

The [online type parser](https://yardoc.org/types.html) is probably the easiest way to check. That says that `Array<Array<String>>` is:

> an Array of (an Array of (Strings))